# Select number from a range

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, select, foreach

I have one specific problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I have DB with a structure:

```
ID NAME    MIN_VALUE    MAX_VALUE    PERCENT
1  Name1   0            500          40
2  Name2   501          5000         30
3  Name4   5001         5000000      20
```

Now the question is how can I select "PERCENT" From this db if search string is 1021 (so it's between 501 and 5000,, and I need to add 30% on some number)

I tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE min_value < STRING < max_value
```

But it's not working.

Can this be done with MySQL or should I use PHP. But I just don't have IDEA how to solve this problem.

With kind regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM DB.table1 `
WHERE floor(1021*1.30) BETWEEN min_value+1 AND max_value-1
```

Do remember that `BETWEEN` is all-inclusive, so this code is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM DB.table1 
WHERE floor(1021*1.30) >= (min_value+1) AND floor(1021*1.30) <= (max_value -1)
```

Comment: BETWEEN includes the end points, but the question states `min_value < STRING < max_value`, indicating the end points should be excluded.

Comment: @JoeStefanelli, I did note that, but updated the question to make it extra clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Between](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) ( http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp )

```
SELECT percent FROM table WHERE YOUR_VALUE BETWEEN min_value AND max_value
```

Comment: BETWEEN includes the end points, but the question states `min_value < STRING < max_value`, indicating the end points should be excluded.